# Best way to save data in a Java application?

Tags: java, database, settings, state

I'm trying to find the best way to save the state of a simple application.
From a DB point-of-view there are 4/5 tables with date fields and relationships off course.

Because the app is simple, and I want the user to have the option of moving the data around (usb pen, dropbox, etc), I wanted to put all data in a single file.

What is the best way/lib to do this?

XML usually is the best format for this (readability & openness), but I haven't found any great lib for this without doing SAX/DOM.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to use XML, take a look at [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/) for simple serialization of Java objects into XML. Here is ["Two minute tutorial"](http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html).

If you want something simple, standard [Java Properties format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) can be also  a way to store/load some small data.

Comment: java.util.Properties also does XML.

Comment: XStream seems just what I was looking for. Do you know about any code available to optimize writings in this lib? I shouldn't be writing to disk on every change.

Comment: It's totally up to you to initiate writing. XStream won't do any automatic saving for you.

Comment: If you're looking for a fast XML parser than I would go with [Xpp3](http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/xgws/xsoap/xpp/) with XStream. It's super fast and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

consider using plain JAXB annotations that come with the JDK:

```
@XmlRootElement  
private class Foo {  
    @XmlAttribute  
    private String text = "bar";
}
```

here's a [blog-post of mine](http://netzwerg.ch/2007/10/simple-jaxb.html) that gives more details on this simple usage of JAXB (it also mentiones a more "classy" JAXB-based approach -- in case you need better control over your XML schema, e.g. to guarantee backwards compatibility)

Comment: What is the difference to XStream?

Answer (score 0):

2 other options you might consider -

- Hsqldb is a small sql db written in
  java. More relevant for your
  purposes, it can be configured to
  simply write to a csv file as it's
  data store, so you could conceivably
  use it's text output as a portable
  datastore and still use sql, if
  that's what you prefer.
- A second option might be to write the
  datastore directly to a serialized
  file either directly or through a
  library like prevayler. Very good
  performance and simple to implement,
  cons are the fragility and opacity of
  the format.

But if the data is small enough, xml is probably much less bother.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to provide semantic meaning to your data then XML is probably a wrong choice. I would recommend using the fat-free alternative [JSON](http://www.json.org/), which is much more naturally built for data structures.

Comment: JSON hurts to deserialize. No strong typing means you need to know the data structure. Hardly a game breaker, but felt weak when I tried it for Java data retention.